# How to run different tox command inside Jenkins environment?

Tags: python, jenkins, tox

I would like to use different command line arguments for py.test, depending on environment: running locally there should be only default ones, but on Jenkins I would like to add `--junitxml=junit-{envname}.xml`, so the test results could be published in nice format.
I know from [documentation](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html), that there is special `[tox:jenkins]` section, which [should be used](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/src/4dbfb1f1eb86b35cbd2c83461e1e294651e89cf6/tox/config.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#config.py-1207) in case there is defined `'JENKINS_URL'` or `'HUDSON_URL'`. So now I created simple tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35

[tox:jenkins]
commands = echo "We are in JENKINS!"

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/my_module
commands = python setup.py test

deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements_test.txt
```

And have defined `JENKINS_URL` environment variable:

```
export JENKINS_URL=true
```

I expect, that if I run tox, then my original command will be substituted with `echo`, but it doesn't work, instead I end with original command been executed.
Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found the solution myself:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/my_module
commands = py.test {env:CUSTOM_ARGS} ; <== use environment variable here

deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements_test.txt
```

and in Jenkins just define `CUSTOM_ARGS` environment variable like this:

```
export CUSTOM_ARGS="--junitxml=junit.xml"
```

Comment: Hi, where exactly you are setting the environment variable . is it jenkins file or jenkins setup

Comment: afaik this should be in the tox.ini file

Answer (score 1):

You could have used [positional arguments](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/example/general.html#general-tips-and-tricks%20%22posargs%22.).

Like this:

```
commands = py.test --mandatory-flag {posargs:--default-flag}
```

And in Jenkins you can call tox like this:

```
tox -- --override-flag
```

Note the separation with two dashes `--`.